# Designing API Java

Tags: java, rest, api, java-8

I have an API that processes the orders.

```
OrderResult OrderProcessor.process(OrderRequest req)
```

I also have an endpoint where users can send request and get the result. I have been asked to support different OrderTypes.

now these order types may mean different OrderRequest and may have different OrderResult.

In terms of good design should I provide seprate methods for each different order

```
OrderResultABC OrderProcessor.process(OrderRequestABC req) 
OrderResultXYZ OrderProcessor.process(OrderRequestXYZ req)
```

And then provide the endpoints as well. OR should I Juse use abstraction and provide one method and then the Return Type will be returned differently at runTime

```
AbstractOrderResult OrderProcessor.process(AbstractOrderRequest req)
```

Comment: Have you considered any design patterns in this design?

Comment: I am actually trying to find which design pattern would be suitable

Answer (score 2):

I think strategy pattern will fit the problem,you want your code close for modification and open for extension this means you can add new order types but when you want to change functionality of existing order type it shouldn't affect other existing order types.
You should use an interface based design.

```
You need 3 interfaces

    1.OrderResult
    2.OrderRequest
    3.OrderProcessor
```

You need separate order processor classes for each functionality so that they are independent enough.

refer:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is the Facade Pattern. This structural pattern uses an interface to hide the complexity. Usage of one interface which is implemented by multiple other concrete classes.

Here is the example:

- Orders - Interface
- OrderProcesorABC - Class
- OrderProcesorXYZ - Class

Both OrderProcesorABC and OrderProcesorXYZ implement the Orders interface.

In the next step, a facade class called OrderMaker will use concrete classes to delegate calls to these classes.

Please see [this link in tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm) for more information.